# Error while importing seaborn in Anaconda

Tags: python-3.x, import, ipython, seaborn

I'm getting the below error while importing seaborn.

> Installing/Uninstalling is not working.

Copying dll files in win32 folder and setting path didn't work.I'm using 32-bit windows 7 machine. output of sys.path as below :

```
['',
 'C:\\Users\\PAL\\Anaconda3\\python35.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\PAL\\Anaconda3\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\PAL\\Anaconda3\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\PAL\\Anaconda3',
 'C:\\Users\\PAL\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\PAL\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Sphinx-1.4.1-py3.5.egg',
 'C:\\Users\\PAL\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\Users\\PAL\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\PAL\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin',
 'C:\\Users\\PAL\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-23.0.0-py3.5.egg',
 'C:\\Users\\PAL\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions',
 'C:\\Users\\PAL\\.ipython']
```

**Error while importing seaborn:**
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 import seaborn as sns

```
C:\Users\PAL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\__init__.py in <module>()
      4 
      5 # Import seaborn objects
----> 6 from .rcmod import *
      7 from .utils import *
      8 from .palettes import *

C:\Users\PAL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\rcmod.py in <module>()
      6 import matplotlib as mpl
      7 
----> 8 from . import palettes, _orig_rc_params
      9 
     10 

C:\Users\PAL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\palettes.py in <module>()
     10 from .external.six.moves import range
     11 
---> 12 from .utils import desaturate, set_hls_values, get_color_cycle
     13 from .xkcd_rgb import xkcd_rgb
     14 from .crayons import crayons

C:\Users\PAL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\utils.py in <module>()
      6 
      7 import numpy as np
----> 8 from scipy import stats
      9 import pandas as pd
     10 import matplotlib as mpl

C:\Users\PAL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\__init__.py in <module>()
    336 from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import
    337 
--> 338 from .stats import *
    339 from .distributions import *
    340 from .morestats import *

C:\Users\PAL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py in <module>()
    178 from scipy._lib.six import callable, string_types
    179 from numpy import array, asarray, ma, zeros
--> 180 import scipy.special as special
    181 import scipy.linalg as linalg
    182 import numpy as np

C:\Users\PAL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\special\__init__.py in <module>()
    625 from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import
    626 
--> 627 from ._ufuncs import *
    628 
    629 from .basic import *
```

> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be
>   found.

Comment: If you look at the stack trace, the error is getting raised when seaborn is trying to import scipy. It looks like you have some problem with your scipy.

Comment: i tried pip install and uninstall scipy and numpy. in my conda list i'm getting 2 numpy and 2 seaborn. and the error is now no module named scipy.